# how can the menu bar closer to the side

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to do an AppBar following the Material UI document, but I don't know why it can't closer to the side.

I want the logo and the button can closer to the side(See the picture).

I tried different methods, but it still does not work. Following in my code, do you know what's the problem with my code?

[image]

It is the code of the AppBar. Thank you so much for your help!

```
<AppBar position="fixed" color="inherit">
                <Container maxWidth="xl">
                    <Toolbar >
                        <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }} >
                            <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' }, mr: 1 }} />
                            <Typography
                                variant="h6"
                                noWrap
                                component="a"
                                href="/"
                                sx={{
                                    mr: 2,
                                    display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
                                    fontFamily: 'monospace',
                                    fontWeight: 700,
                                    letterSpacing: '.3rem',
                                    color: 'inherit',
                                    textDecoration: 'none',
                                }}
                            >
                                LOGO
                            </Typography>
                        </Box>
                        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, }}>
                            <IconButton
                                size="large"
                                aria-label="account of current user"
                                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
                                color="inherit"
                            >
                                <MenuIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Menu
                                id="menu-appbar"
                                anchorEl={anchorElNav}
                                anchorOrigin={{
                                    vertical: 'bottom',
                                    horizontal: 'left',
                                }}
                                keepMounted
                                transformOrigin={{
                                    vertical: 'top',
                                    horizontal: 'left',
                                }}
                                open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
                                onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
                                sx={{
                                    display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' }
                                }}
                            >
                                {pages.map((page) => (
                                    <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                                        <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </Menu>
                        </Box>
                        <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} />
                        <Typography
                            variant="h5"
                            noWrap
                            component="a"
                            href="/"
                            sx={{
                                mr: 2,
                                display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
                                flexGrow: 1,
                                fontFamily: 'monospace',
                                fontWeight: 700,
                                letterSpacing: '.3rem',
                                color: 'inherit',
                                textDecoration: 'none',
                            }}
                        >
                            LOGO
                        </Typography>
                        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}
                            justifyContent="center"
                            alignItems="center">
                            {pages.map((page) => (
                                <Button
                                    key={page}
                                    onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                                    sx={{ my: 2, color: 'inherit', display: 'block' }}
                                >
                                    {page}
                                </Button>
                            ))}
                        </Box>

                        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
                            <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
                                free to try
                            </Button>
                        </Box>
                    </Toolbar>
                </Container>
            </AppBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem is a Container. When I delete the Container, then the problem has been solved.